# customize the image by user and save with white background

Tags: javascript, css, image, d3.js, svg

I am saving the D3.js svg as an image with white background, but it doesn't save it with white background, the background is transparent.
How can I let the user to choose if he wants with transparent or white background? and the same for resolution? how can the user choose the resolution himself?

here is my javascript code:

```
function savePNG() {

    var html = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("version", 1.1)
        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
        .style('fill', 'white')
        .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(html);
    window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(html)))
    image.onload = start;

    function start()
    {
        // scale the image * 5 (max)
        var c1 = scaleIt(image,5);

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = c1.width;
        canvas.height = c1.height;
        canvas.style.background = 'white';
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(c1, 0, 0);


        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download = "image.png";
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    }

    function scaleIt(image,scaleFactor)
    {
        var c = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
        var w = image.width*scaleFactor;
        var h = image.height*scaleFactor;
        c.width = w;
        c.height = h;
        ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,w,h);
        return(c);
    }
}
```

and here is the html button that generates the image:

```
<button id="saveimage" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="savePNG()">Save D3 svg</button>
```

Comment: With jquery. jquery can solve everything.

Comment: @Lain please provide an answer so that i can see what you mean exactly; thanks

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492

Comment: If I remember correctly, a man has to draw a white reactangle in the size of the canvas first, before drawing the image on it. The style background-color is just for the browser.

Comment: Just posted an answer in the second it got closed: https://jsfiddle.net/cqpnd63f/